# Added margin HTML

Tags: html, css, margin

In HTML, I am trying to make a footer but every time I do this it just comes like this with an added margin on the left.

[image] 
 
this is my footer code;

```
<div id="footer"> tester </div>
   #footer {
   background-image: url(images/backgroundrpatternfooter.png);
   background-repeat: repeat;
   position : absolute;
   bottom : 0;
   height : 40px;
   width : 1800px;
   margin: 0;
   }
```

Comment: possibly this `footer` wrapped on another div which have some `margin:left` added.

Comment: Recreate this on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). It will help others debug it better.

Comment: Try adding in an additional attribute to your footer css `clear:both;` and instead of using div with id footer use `<footer>` tag directly

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies not within the footer `div`, but within the `body`. The `body` element has a default margin of 8px (might depend on the browser you're using), so you need to set the `body`'s margin to 0 like this:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

[Working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/michaelvandeweerd/w2vx4496/)

I would also like to suggest that you look into using the `footer` element instead of using a `div` as a footer, it was added to HTML5 for that very purpose!

I hope this helped and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="footer"> tester </div>
#footer {
    background-image: url(images/backgroundrpatternfooter.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    position : absolute;
    bottom : 0;
    height : 40px;
    width : 1800px;
    margin: 0;
    **left:0;**
}
```

Try adding left:0;, if still not working check your inherit css.

Answer (score -2):

Your CSS indicates a fixed with of `1800px` but since your element is absolutely positioned, you need to add a `margin-left` or `left` property to specify where the element should be positioned from (`margin-right` and `right` also work).

Do you want your element centered? Try using

```
left: 50%
```

to achieve that.

Also, try adding

```
left: 0;
```

and see if that removes the gap you're dealing with.

(The gap is probably caused by your containing element being wider than 1800 px).